# How to combine sql querie?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three table:

**Table: car**

```
id integer
owner integer
color varchar
type varchar
productor integer
date_of_produce integer
```

**Table owner**

```
id integer
first_name varchar
last_name varchar
address varchar
birth_date integer
place_of_birth varchar
email varchar
```

**Table: producer**

```
id integer
name varchar
address_of_producer varchar
email varchar
```

How can I combine the two queries to get the most frequent type of car between owners, who are older than 25 years old?

SELECT type FROM `car` INNER JOIN owner ON car.tulajdonos = owner.id WHERE 2018 - owner.birth_date <= 25

SELECT type, COUNT(type) c FROM `car` GROUP BY type ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sounds like homework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at using joins.  At the end of your first select statement:

FROM car
JOIN
owner on owner.id = car.owner

Comment: So finally it can be:
SELECT type, COUNT(type) AS Frequency
FROM car GROUP BY car ORDER BY COUNT(type) DESC
WHERE (date_of_produce - 2018) >= 25

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the 2 queries in your question.

1. The first query does `Group by car`; but `Group by` needs to be given column(s) to group by, not a table name. The columns given [must be the non-aggregated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) from the query.
2. The second query does `FROM owner WHERE (date_of_produce`; but that column does not exist in that table.
3. There is an ambiguity in the question; but I think you have interpreted it incorrectly. *"which type of car is the most frequent between the owners who are more than 25 years old"* - I think the *25 years old* refers to the owners, not the cars.

Try creating the query for the 25 year old owners, then adapt that into a query for which cars they own, then adapt that into a query for the most frequent.

Although you have accepted the answer which suggests a JOIN, I think the solution does not require one.